# Liferay WebContentDisplay - Portlet - hide configuration tabs

Tags: configuration, content-management-system, liferay

How to hide some configuration tabs by WebContentDisplay-Portlet. I would let only the main configuration and deactivate the rest of tabs or hide them.

[image: Configuration of WebContentDisplay-Portlet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide tabs for configuration of all portlets than you can add this to your css

```
#_86_tabs1supported-clientsTabsId,
#_86_tabs1permissionsTabsId,
#_86_tabs1sharingTabsId,
#_86_tabs1scopeTabsId {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to hide them, or even not render them, than you should create hook and in it modify this jsp

```
/portal-src/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/portlet_configuration/tabs1.jsp
```

, also take a look at

```
/portal/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/portlet_configuration/init.jsp
```

For **example**, in tabs1.jsp find

```java
if (Validator.isNotNull(selPortlet.getConfigurationActionClass())) {
    tabs1Names += ",setup";

    request.setAttribute("liferay-ui:tabs:url" + pos++, configurationURL.toString());
}
```

below that enter

```java
boolean showSystemTabs = true;
if ("56".equeals(portletResource)) {
   showSystemTabs = false;
}
```

note that 56 is id of "Web Content Display" portlet.

After that you can change (beneath it)

```java
if (selPortlet.hasMultipleMimeTypes()) {
    tabs1Names += ",supported-clients";

    request.setAttribute("liferay-ui:tabs:url" + pos++, supportedClientsURL.toString());
}
```

to

```java
if (selPortlet.hasMultipleMimeTypes() && showSystemTabs) {
    tabs1Names += ",supported-clients";

    request.setAttribute("liferay-ui:tabs:url" + pos++, supportedClientsURL.toString());
}
```

and same logic for other tabs.

Be aware that hooks are applied to all communities, user pages ...